# Adding Nested Key To JSON Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm just starting to learn Javascript so my apologies if this is a stupid question.

Basically my issue is this:

Via an external form that I cannot change, I am receiving the following data.

```
var data = "{\"status\": \"created\", \"name\": \"mike\", \"roleName\": \"Signer\", \"emailSubject\": \"test\", \"email\": \"hellO@yahoo.com\", \"templateId\": \"0171502E-38F7-43A7-BA09-6FC1FDAB09C2\" }"
```

Before I can send the data via API, the documentation requires that I add an additional nested key (templateRoles) to wrap rolename, emailsubject, and email into a new array. The final results is suppose to look like this.

```
var data = "{\"status\": \"created\", \"name\": \"mike\", \"templateRoles\": [{ \"roleName\": \"Signer\", \"emailSubject\": \"test\", \"email\": \"hellO@yahoo.com\"}], \"templateId\": \"0171502E-38F7-43A7-BA09-6FC1FDAB09C2\"}"
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this. I've tried using splice and replace but either I am doing it wrong or that isn't the right approach. Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this flow : `JSON.parse`, add custom key as a normal js object, `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: You may want to look at my answer for a full answer to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse(data)` to convert your JSON string into an object. Then you can manipulate that object. Once you're done manipulating simply use `JSON.stringify()` to get a JSON string back.

Sample code:

```
var data = "{\"status\": \"created\", \"name\": \"mike\", \"templateId\": \"0171502E-38F7-43A7-BA09-6FC1FDAB09C2\", \"templateRoles\": [{ \"roleName\": \"Signer\", \"emailSubject\": \"test\", \"email\": \"hellO@yahoo.com\"}]}";

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
jsonObj.templateRoles = "some roles here";

var newDataStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

Comment: Thanks. Okay I have done that. Now what would be the best way to manipulate the object to add in tempalteRoles?

Comment: @MichaelKlump you need to use dot or bracket notation to add new keys or modify existing ones. Have a look at the code sample I provided.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. I got it working! One final question, is it possible to pass variable when you manipulate the object? Right now I have this jsonObj.templateRoles = [ { 'email' : 'hello@gmail.com', 'roleName' : 'CEO', 'name' : 'Donald Duck' } ];. But is it possible to do something like this where the fields are filled dynamically with user data? jsonObj.templateRoles = [ { 'email' : 'definedvariable.email', 'roleName' : 'definedvariable.roleName', 'name' : 'definedVariable.name' } ];

Comment: @MichaelKlump yes, it's possible. Just declare the variable and add it without using quotes. See this JSBin for an example: http://jsbin.com/licabapu/1/edit?js,console. If this answered your question then please remember to mark it as the chosen answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again for your help. You really saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

So your basic code would look like this. Make the JSON string a JavaScript object, then manipulate it as such. Afterwards you can use `JSON.stringyfi` to put back to a JSON string.

```
var jsonData = "{\"status\": \"created\", \"name\": \"mike\", \"templateId\": \"0171502E-38F7-43A7-BA09-6FC1FDAB09C2\", \"roleName\": \"Signer\", \"emailSubject\": \"test\", \"email\": \"hellO@yahoo.com\"}";

var parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonData);

// now manipulate

parsedJson.newProperty = "hey there";

parsedJson.status = "not created";
```

As a side note, I don't think you can order the keys, so you can do whatever in terms of adding properties or functions. Never rely on the keys to be in order. And by key, I mean property of function name of the object. Objects are held in a dictionary type way where their keys hold information.

So:

```
parsedJson["created"]
```

Is the same as

```
parsedJson.created
```

You can conditionally add data depending on whether a key exists:

```
for (var key in parsedJson)
    if (key === "someKey")
        // do something
```

OR

```
if (parsedJson["someKey"] === undefined)
    // do something
```